# Remainder operator (%)

Tags: java

Скачал туториал по Java с Oracle. Сижу, вчитываюсь. Тема "операторы".
Чему равны переменные i и n в двух послед. выражениях:

```
int i = 10;
int n = i++%5;
--------------
int i = 10;
int n = ++i%5;
```

У меня полкчается, что в 1ом i==11 и n==1, а во втором ... так же, посколько, на сколько я понял, приоритет у унарной операции выше, чем "умножение-деление-остаток от деления".
Подскажите в чём я косячу, а?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первом случае i = 11, а n = 0. Во втором  i = 11, n = 1. Разница в префиксной и постфиксной формах инкремента. Приоритет у операций инкремента выше, однако постфиксный выполняется после выполнения основного выражения.

Comment: всё понял, спасибо!